# Are there advantages to using IntegerChoices field in a Django model if it's not shown to users?

Tags: django, django-models, django-model-field

I'm using `IntegerChoices` in my Django (3.2) model.

```py
class AType(db.IntegerChoices):
    UNKNOWN = 0, 'Unknown'
    SOMETHING = 1, 'Something'
    ANOTHER_THING = 2, 'Another thing'
    A_THIRD_THING = 3, 'A third thing'


class MyObject(models.Model):
    a_type = db.IntegerField(choices=AType.choices)
```

(I've changed the choices to be more generic.)

Every time I add a value to AType, it produces a DB migration, which I faithfully apply.

`a_type` is strictly behind the scenes.  Users never see it, so it's only in the admin UI, but I don't need it to be editable.  So forms aren't really used.

Is there any impact on the DB (e.g., constraints) of these migrations?

Is there any other utility to having an IntegerChoices field, given that it's not displayed to a (non-staff) user, and not in a form?

If there's no utility, I'm thinking of just changing `MyObject.a_type` to an IntegerField, and continuing to use `AType` everywhere, but not having all the migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any impact on the DB (e.g., constraints) of these migrations?

No impact to the schema. You can see this in `python manage.py sqlmigrate myapp 000x_mymigration`.

However, it still does `CREATE TABLE`, `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` (expensive), `DROP TABLE`, `ALTER TABLE`.

This is "by design" and "wontfix":

- [#22837 (Migrations detect unnessecary(?) changes) — Django](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22837)
- [#30048 (Migrations created when verbose_name or help_text is changed) – Django](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30048)

> Is there any other utility to having an IntegerChoices field, given that it's not displayed to a (non-staff) user, and not in a form?

Yes, model validation.
Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#choices

> I'm thinking of just changing `MyObject.a_type` to an IntegerField, and continuing to use `AType` everywhere, but not having all the migrations.

You can ignore `choices` by patching `MigrationAutodetector` in `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

You can additionally ignore `_verbose_name` and `help_text`.

mysite/apps.py:

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.core.management.commands import makemigrations, migrate
from django.db import models
from django.db.migrations import autodetector


class MigrationAutodetector(autodetector.MigrationAutodetector):
    ignored_field_attribute_names = [
        'choices',
        # '_verbose_name',
        # 'help_text',
    ]

    def deep_deconstruct(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, models.Field):
            for attr_name in self.ignored_field_attribute_names:
                setattr(obj, attr_name, None)
        return super().deep_deconstruct(obj)


class MySiteAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'mysite'

    def ready(self):
        makemigrations.MigrationAutodetector = MigrationAutodetector
        migrate.MigrationAutodetector = MigrationAutodetector
        pass
```

mysite/settings.py:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'mysite.apps.MySiteAppConfig',
]
```

Comment: Thanks! But, model validation is used for forms, right? If I'm not using forms, is there other value to choices?

Comment: Oh, I guess not.